# Integration issues with Microsoft Sentinel and ServiceNow and Get Etag

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, servicenow, etag, azure-sentinel

Working on the Microsoft Sentinel to ServiceNow integration as documented in [Microsoft Azure to ServiceNow Article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sentinel/azure-sentinel-incident-bi-directional-sync-with-servicenow/ba-p/1667771).  I am running into an issue

> 
> InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'GEt_incident_-_bring_fresh_Etag' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language expression 'body('Parse_JSON_2')?['value']?[0]['SubId']' cannot be evaluated because property 'SubId' cannot be selected. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.

I have been trying to break this down as to what the message is saying, particularly in this piece,

> The template language expression 'body('Parse_JSON_2')?['value']?[0]['SubId']' cannot be evaluated because property 'SubId' cannot be selected.
> Or more so this,
> The template language expression XXX cannot be evaluated because property 'SubId' cannot be selected.

Is the "cannot be selected," indicating that there is a permission problem? I am using the system identity

[image]

[image]

Where the roles are assigned are

[image]

I am open to considering any thoughts or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the post deployments steps on Github?  The state you need to grant **Sentinel Reader** role to the managed identity.

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Sentinel/tree/master/Playbooks/Create-SNOW-record#post-deployment